# Android App Testing for Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, emulation

I want to test my app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab device emulator. But I don't have one installed. I want to know where can I get it from? I am using Eclipse Galileo.

Many Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxy Tab Emulator is already coming with the new SDK

If you have the updated SDK Manager (R_08) then you can download the Emulator as an add-on.

Download the new SDK Manager from the Android developer site, and try to update the platforms that you already have. It will give you option to download Samsung Galaxy Tab Emulator.

If you jump into any problem, hit it back here, or contact me via www.sheikhaman.com

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do.